# Design a input box with extended lines

Tags: html, css

I am trying to code an input box like in the image below.

[image]

However, I only end up with part of the lines with the current code.
When it's a button rather than an edit, everything in fine.

```css
.sidebar-search input {
    display: inline-block;
    border-color: #ffd717 -moz-use-text-color #ffd717 #ffd717;
    border-style: solid none solid solid;
    border-width: 2px 0 2px 0px;
    color: #ffd717;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar-search input::before,
.sidebar-search input::after {
    content: '';
    width: 2px;
    height: 160%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30%;
    background-color: #FFD717;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.sidebar-search input::before {
    left: 10%;
}

.sidebar-search input::after {
    right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="right-sidebar-area">
  <div class="single-right-sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-search">
      <input type="text" name="Search">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. It looks like `::before` and `::after` pseudo-selectors don't work for `input` elements, so apply it directly to `sidebar-search` and add more styles to that `div`

```css
.sidebar-search {
  /*specify positioning, height and width */
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 175px;
}

.sidebar-search input {
    display: inline-block;
    border-color: #ffd717 -moz-use-text-color #ffd717 #ffd717;
    border-style: solid none solid solid;
    border-width: 2px 0 2px 0px;
    color: #ffd717;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar-search::before,
.sidebar-search::after {
    content: '';
    width: 2px;
    height: 160%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30%;
    background-color: #FFD717;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.sidebar-search::before {
    left: 10px; /*these values are more accurate according to the picture */
}

.sidebar-search::after {
    right: 10px; /*these values are more accurate according to the picture */
}
```

```html
<div class="right-sidebar-area">
  <div class="single-right-sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-search">
      <input type="text" name="Search">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this advice. Actually I am new user.. :) Now answare accepted.